# Ensure valid XHTML from a string in PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I'm using XHTML Transitional doctype for displaying content in a browser. But, the content is displayed it is passed through a XML Parser (DOMDocument) for giving final touches before outputting to the browser.

I use a custom designed CMS for my website, that allows me to make changes to the site. I have a module that allows me to display HTML scripts on my website in a way similar to WordPress widgets.

The problem i am facing right now is that I need to make sure any code provided through this module should be in a valid XHTML format or else the module will need to convert the code to valid XHTML. Currently if a portion of the input code is not XHTML compliant then my XML parser breaks and throws warnings.

What I am looking for is a solution that encodes the entities present in the URLs and text portions of the input provided via TextArea control. For example the following string will break the parser giving entity reference error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.abcxyz.com/foo?bar=1&sumthing"></script>
```

Also the following line would cause same error:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com">Books & Cool stuff<a/>
```

P.S. If i use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`, they also convert the angle brackets of tags, which is not required. I just need the urls and text portions of the string to be escaped/encoded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
Waqar Mushtaq

Comment: Normalize it with [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) first.

Comment: A proper solution to XML escaping woes would be http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/xhp-a-new-way-to-write-php/294003943919 - but that's fairly non-standard. So to keep the output XHTML syntax compliant (even if you are actually sending it with the wrong MIME type), is in fact to pipe it through libtidy.

Comment: thanks "hakre" you saved my day. Is tidy performance effective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested in a quick comment, you can solve the problem with the [PHP tidy extension<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) quite comfortable.

To convert a HTML fragment - even a good tag soup - into something `DomDocument` or `SimpleXML` can deal with, you can use something like the following:

```
$config = array(
    'output-xhtml' => 1,
    'show-body-only' => 1
);
$fragment = tidy_repair_string($html, $config);
$xhtml = sprintf("<body>%s</body>", $fragment);
```

*Example:* Format tag soup html as valid xhtml with [`tidy_repair_string`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php).

[Tidy has many options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html), these two used are needed for fragments and XHTML compatibility.

The only problem left now is that this XHTML fragment can contain entities that `DomDocument` or `SimpleXML` do not understand, for example `&nbsp;`. This and others are undefined in XML.

As far as `DomDocument` is concerned (you wrote you use it), it supports [loading html](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) instead of xml as well which deals with those entities:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($xhtml);
```

*Example:* Loading HTML with DomDocument

Comment: Thanks tidy really helped. Just one more question. Is is an overhead to first parse the text using tidy and then load into XML parser?

Comment: @Waqar Mushtaq: If it actually allows your system to run as intended, I would not consider it overhead but necessary. You can try if `$dom->loadHTML($fragment);` already does the job however.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need to do is generate valid XHTML in the first place. All your attributes much be htmlentitied.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.abcxyz.com/foo?bar=1&sumthing"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.abcxyz.com/foo?bar=1&amp;sumthing"></script>
```

and

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com">Books & Cool stuff</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com">Books &amp; Cool stuff</a>
```

It's not easy to always generate valid XHTML. If at all possible I would recommend you find some other way of doing the post processing.

Comment: thanks for sharing this but, it would not be feasible to modify each and every code snippet before pasting into the textarea control. I would my backend to take care of it.

Comment: Then you can't do it, or there will be cases where the output will be malformed.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Tidy is a computer program and a library whose purpose is to fix invalid HTML and to improve the layout and indent style of the resulting markup.

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Examples of bad HTML it is able to fix:

- Missing or mismatched end tags, mixed up tags
- Adding missing items (some tags, quotes, ...)
- Reporting proprietary HTML extensions
- Change layout of markup to predefined style
- Transform characters from some encodings into HTML entities